# Write to Custom Binary File from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, streamwriter

First of all, I'm loading up a fairly large file into a data grid view (~100MB). The file contains dozens of "profiles". The user is able to select which profile they want to view after it gets loaded into the data grid view.
What I want to do is enable the user to select a specific profile and have them save it as an individual file so that they don't have to open up a large file every time. 
Here is how the file is loaded (note that it's databound with the data grid view):

```
    private void boardListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (boardListView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            var s = (BoardCandidateOffset)boardListView.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
            LoadFromFile(s);
            plotModel.ResetAllAxes();
            plotView.InvalidatePlot(true);
        }
    }
```

And here is where I read the file:

```
    private void LoadFromFile(BoardCandidateOffset b)
    {
        profiles.Clear();
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(CurrentFileName))
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            stream.Seek(b.FileOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Count; i++)
            {
                profiles.Add(CustProfileList.ReadFromBinaryReader(reader));
            }
        }
    }
```

And here I attempt to write the selected profile to a new file:

```
    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (boardListView.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveBoard = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveBoard.DefaultExt = ".prof";

            if (saveBoard.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (Stream stream = File.Create(saveBoard.FileName))
                {
                    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                    {
                        foreach(var p in profiles)
                        {
                            p.WriteToBinaryWriter(writer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else return;
    }
```

Unfortunately though, I'm getting nothing from this in the file I create. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say you're "getting nothing", is the file empty? Is it full of  zero bytes, or is it zero bytes in length? Does it even exist? Have you tried putting a breakpoint in `saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click` and looking at `profiles[boardListView.CurrentCell.RowIndex]` in the watch window? By the way, it's a bad idea to use your UI controls as your data structure, and a bad idea to put all your logic in event handlers. Everything ends up being a convoluted hairball that way. Some kind of MVC-ish architecture stars paying off at a much smaller project size than you might think.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, the file gets created, its about 1kb. The contents of it are `Common.Profiles`, which is referring to the custom `List`, `Profiles`. The actual list `profiles` contains all the profiles from the file, however, it doesn't appear to be getting into the file.

Comment: *"The actual list profiles contains all the profiles from the file, however, it doesn't appear to be getting into the file."* How many different files are you talking about in that sentence? And how many profiles? I thought you had a list of many profiles, which was stored in File A, and read into a list and/or a grid. And I thought you were trying to export ONE of those profiles into File B. Is that in the ballpark?

Comment: Okay...I have a file, and its partitioned out into many "sections". These sections end up being the individual cells in the data grid view. And each of these "sections" contain hundreds of profiles. What I want to do is end up saving just the current selected "section". Which would be `profiles`, so I'll correct that in the code above from `profiles[boardListView.CurrentCell.RowIndex]` to `profiles`. After doing this, the file I create is empty.

Comment: Can we get back to precisely what you mean by "empty"? When you open the file in Visual Studio using the "Open With" option from the drop-down arrow menu in the Open button on the Open File dialog, what do you see? When you put a breakpoint in the function where you write to the StreamWriter, what are you seeing in the array of bytes that's being written? Is the StreamWriter writing as binary or text? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is `profiles` an array of bytes, or something more complicated like `List<T>` for example?

Comment: I literally mean empty...as if you've just created a brand new file. It appears that nothing gets written.

Comment: So the 1kb file is a different one?

Comment: `profiles` is a bunch of different components in a list (e.g. x coordinate, y coordinate, color, etc.)

Comment: Yes, after making the edit mentioned above, its just empty now.

Comment: So `profiles` isn't an array of bytes. Can you tell me the exact runtime type you see for it when you type `profiles.GetType()` in the watch window? I don't see how any of StreamWriter.Write()'s [innumerable overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write(v=vs.110).aspx) can guess how you want to serialize that structure to a binary file. I'm guessing `CustProfileList.ReadFromBinaryReader()` reads binary and returns something else. Is there a complementary write method, something like `CustProfileList.WriteToBinaryReader()`?

Comment: Yes, there is. But I can't access it from `CustProfileList`, because it doesn't return anything: `public void WriteToBinaryWriter(BinaryWriter bw)`

Comment: I can't even guess what you mean when you say "I can't access it from CustProfileList, because it doesn't return anything". Can you explain to me, like I'm five, what actions you performed when you "tried to access it", and what happened to make you think your attempt wasn't successful? And finally how did you identify `void` as the problem? For a moment, pretend I'm not as technical as you are, and I need everything spelled out.

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you create a `BinaryWriter` which will write to the file you want to write to, and pass it it to `CustProfileList.WriteToBinaryWriter`.

Comment: I've made some changes (edit made above) and it loads up all the profiles as expected. However, when I try to open the file nothing shows up in the data grid view. When I check to see if anything is being passed in, it shows that its `Count` is zero.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like a fewer minor changes and I got it working:) Thank you for your help!